# awesome does not recognize PATH change

Tags: path, zsh, awesome-wm

I use zsh as my login shell, lightdm as login manager and awesome as window manager.

I changed the `PATH` Variable in my `~/.zshrc` and it works on the terminal, but awesome itself does not recognize the Variable change. where do i need to put the changes that i can use the `PATH` in awesome?

I dont want to put some of the PATH Stuff into /etc/rc.local or similar, because it contains user specific folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `lightdm` does not execute an interactive shell to start `awesome`. So your `~/.zshrc` isn't sourced -- simply use `~/.zshenv` instead, which get sourced regardless if the shell is a login shell and / or an interactive shell.

From the man page:

> **STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES**
>
> Commands are first read from `/etc/zshenv` (...)
>
> Commands are then read from `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`.  If the shell is a *login shell*, commands are  read  from  `/etc/zprofile`  and  then
>          `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`.  Then, if the shell is *interactive*, commands are read from `/etc/zshrc` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`.  Finally,
>   if
>          the shell is a *login shell*, `/etc/zlogin` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin` are read.
>    (...)
>
> If `ZDOTDIR` is unset, `HOME` is used instead.

Comment: This is helpful, but it has the disadvantage of interfering with all zsh scripts, whether interactive or not.

Comment: @Owen: You are absolutely right; you should put as few as possible to _zshenv_. However, if you break your system / scripts by changing `$PATH` (which was th OP's question), you should think about other means to reach your goal and don't change `$PATH` at all, neither in _zshenv_ nor _zshrc_.